# Error when opening package explorer and when trying to open java classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, helios

Getting this strange error in Eclipse (Helios). I can't show the package explorer.

> Could not create the view:
>   org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/tostringgeneration/ToStringGenerationSettings
>   (wrong name:
>   org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/tostringgeneration/ToStringGenerationSettings$CustomBuilderSettings)

Same error when trying to open a java class file. Any clues?

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. Has it worked before or is it a fresh eclipse installation? What have you done? Have you installed a new plugin? Switched a workspace? Moved eclipse?

Comment: Seems like reinstalling Eclipse to a different directory would be quicker than figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Arne's and Gilbert's comments.  If this is still an issue, a few things you can try to resolve:

- Try a new workspace (using the same Eclipse installation).
- Trying a new Eclipse installation (using your same workspace).  This would also be a good chance to upgrade to the latest version of Eclipse, now 3.7 / Indigo.

(Primarily posting this answer in an attempt to either get this question some additional attention / competitive answers, or at the least, to simply remove this from the growing list of unanswered questions.)